# Last build label version number for Continuous and Nightly build is not same

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have configured two project builds - **Continuous and nightly** in my CruiseControl.Net (version: 1.6.7981.1) server to build the same project code.

I am getting code from TFS server and storing it in **same working directory** for both the builds and I have applied assemblyVersionLabeller in both the project builds.

Continuous build builds only if modification exists and nightly build (forcebuild) builds at 5:00 AM.

**My problem is**: when nightly build finishes building, revision number of last build label must be either equels to continuous builds revision number  or higher then that.(i.e. If my continuous build lable is 1.0.125.23884 then after nightly build finishes, nightly builds lable must be x.x.x.23884 or more then 23884 but it is less then that like 23875).

My ccnet.config looks like this:

```
<cruisecontrol>

<project name="Myproject-Continuous Build">
   <triggers>
       <intervalTrigger seconds="600" buildCondition="IfModificationExists"/>
   </triggers>

<labeller type="assemblyVersionLabeller">
  <major>1</major>
  <minor>0</minor>
  <incrementOnFailure>false</incrementOnFailure>
</labeller>

<sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true">
  <server>server path</server>
  <username>"username"</username>
  <password>password</password>
  <project>$Project/Source</project>
  <workingDirectory>F:\WD</workingDirectory>
  <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
</sourcecontrol>

  <tasks>
    <msbuild>
      <executable>C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
      <workingDirectory>F:\FD</workingDirectory>
      <projectFile>"Project.sln"</projectFile>
      <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /noconsolelogger /v:diag</buildArgs>
      <targets>ReBuild</targets>
    </msbuild>
  </tasks>
</project>

<project name="Myproject-Nightly Build">
   <triggers>
        <scheduleTrigger time="5:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild"/>
   </triggers>

  <labeller type="assemblyVersionLabeller">
     <major>1</major>
     <minor>0</minor>
     <incrementOnFailure>false</incrementOnFailure>
  </labeller>

  <sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true">
     <server>server path</server>
     <username>"username"</username>
     <password>password</password>
     <project>$Project/Source</project>
     <workingDirectory>F:\WD</workingDirectory>
     <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
  </sourcecontrol>

  <tasks>
    <msbuild>
      <executable>C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
      <workingDirectory>F:\FD</workingDirectory>
      <projectFile>"Project.sln"</projectFile>
      <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /noconsolelogger /v:diag</buildArgs>
      <targets>ReBuild</targets>
    </msbuild>
  </tasks>

</project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Pleaes help
Thanks|GDG

Answer (score 0):

You mixed something up: The build number is the 3rd element whereas the 4th element is the revision number. The build number is incremented with every successful build if you don't specify it explicitly. The revision number - if not specified - is the LastChangeNumber, provided by some VCS. Find more information in [CCNET documentation on Assembly Version Labeller](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Assembly_Version_Labeller).

Comment: Ye you are right, but I am talking about revision number only.

Comment: The point is: The revision number is not determined by CCNET but by your VCS

Comment: I hunted down what is contained in the revision number in our particular case. We have a similar configuration: Major and minor version defined explicitly, build number controlled by CCNET, revision number controlled by VCS (Seapine Surround in our case). The revision number is determined as the VCS version of the one source file in the build triggering changeset which was changed most recently. So the revision number appears to be somehow arbitrary and not actually useful